# Page extends when I want only a scrollable element

Tags: html, css

Alright, I hope this all makes sense.

I have a webpage where I'd like to have the header AND the footer visible on the screen regardless of window size.  In between the header and footer, I have 2 sections, the one on the left is a scrollable div section, the one on the right is a static section (it will not be filled with enough content to need any scrolling.

---

Here is an example of my **HTML** when the scrollable div will NOT need any scrolling (maximized on a full HD monitor):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1>header</h1>
    </header>
    
<div id="app-page">
    <div id="scrollable-section">
        <div class="app-header">
            <h1>App Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="scrollable-content">
            <h3>Subsection 1</h3>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="static-section">
        <h1>Static Header</h1>
        <p>static content</p>
    </div>
</div>


    <footer>
        <h1>footer</h1>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Here is an example of the **same HTML**, but with enough "Lorem Ipsum" that the scrollable div WILL need scrolling:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1>header</h1>
    </header>
    
<div id="app-page">
    <div id="scrollable-section">
        <div class="app-header">
            <h1>App Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="scrollable-content">
            <h3>Subsection 1</h3>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <br>
            <h3>Subsection 2</h3>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <br>
            <h3>Subsection 3</h3>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <br>
            <h3>Subsection 4</h3>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="static-section">
        <h1>Static Header</h1>
        <p>static content</p>
    </div>
</div>


    <footer>
        <h1>footer</h1>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Here is the **CSS**:

```
/* Base */

html, body{
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Header */

header{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

header h1{
    margin: 0;
}

/* Page Content */

div#app-page{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

div#scrollable-section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

div.app-header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 25px;
}

div#scrollable-content{
    border: 5px solid blue;
    margin: 0 50px;
    padding: 20px;
}

div#static-section{
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Footer */

footer{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

---

Here's my problem:

Full screen, the first HTML looks perfect.  But when populated with enough content to need scrolling (the second HTML), not only does a scroll bar appear for the scrollable div, but one also appears on the far right for the full page.  This is because the footer dips just below the window and I no longer can view both the footer and header at the same time.

Additionally, when I resize the window on my first HTML, the same issue happens.

I have the CSS for my footer setup the way I do because on other pages (without a static section like this) I DO want the page to extend so I can scroll the full page.  I thought that the way I set this page up meant that ONLY the scrollable div would have a scrollbar, but for some reason the full page extends just a little bit.  I want only the 1 scrollbar, what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your header and footer to always be visible, set their positions to `position: fixed;` and use `top:0;` for the header / `bottom:0;` for the footer.

If you don't want the whole page to scroll, set `body {overflow: hidden;}`

Then you'll probably have to set the div to `overflow:scroll;` independently.

Is this what you're looking for? I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, for my purposes, all I needed to do was add "overflow: hidden;" to "div#app-page"
Thank you so much for your help!